# Is there any web site to read teeka (tipitaka sub commentaries) in english

Tags: pali-canon, tipitaka

Can you give a link to read teeka or sub commentaries..

Comment: https://archive.org/details/PaliCommentariesCollection (Though most effective way is to learn Pali)

Comment: @Blake that's a great resource! For future readers, most in that link are Aṭṭhakathā; the seven Ṭīkā volumes included are marked with a "B" after the number.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single link you can go to to read subcommentaries. Unlike the Tipiṭaka, Aṭṭhakathā and Ṭīkā aren't standardized across traditions (otherwise they'd be another basket!) and haven't been widely translated. You could find individual translations depending on what you're interested in, and the Sutta Central folks have a long thread on availability of commentaries, including sub-commentaries:

- [Please, help - “Live” List of Pali Commentaries’ English Translations](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/please-help-live-list-of-pali-commentaries-english-translations/16882)

but there is no single comprehensive source for translations of subcommentaries into English.